# Is Qatar still backing any sides in the Yemen conflict?

Tags: foreign-policy, civil-war, qatar, yemen

There are some [news from 2015](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-34173544) that back then Qatar was deploying 1,000 troops in Yemen as part of the Saudi-led coalition.

But after Qatar's [2017 fallout](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-40159080) with the Saudis and much of the Arab world, is Qatar still involved in a significant way in Yemen?

Comment: That is the US-Saudi led war, not just Saudi-led coalition, most of the bombs that are dropped on Yemen are manufactured in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not, at least not in any way that is known publicly. It is widely reported that they withdrew support  in 2017 but I can find no evidence that they reversed this or that they continued to be involved in any significant way.

Comment: Militarily, trade, diplomatically?